# Separating Stylus CSS Defintiions With Semicolons

Tags: css, stylus

Is it possible to separate Stylus definitions with semicolons?

Eg:

```
div.somclass
    color blue; height 20px; border 1px solid blue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJWzzw (view compiled CSS)

```
div.somclass {
  color: #00f;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```